# How to use ActiveSheet property in a Module

Tags: excel, module, vba

I have the following code that works fine for my individual excel sheets (there are a total of 4 sheets). When I try to put this code into a module so that I don't need it on each sheet however, it stops working. I have several other Subs that make use of `Find_Select`, so not being able to put it into a module is forcing me to have a lot of repeat code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
Public Sub Find_Select()

Dim cl As Range
With ActiveSheet.Range("A2:X35")
    Set cl = .Find(rplc, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If cl Is Nothing Then
    Else
        cl.Select
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the trick:

```
Sub Find_Select(rplc)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cl As Range

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    With ws.Range("A2:X35")
        Set cl = .Find(rplc, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If cl Is Nothing Then
        Else
            cl.Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```